# Is there a way to get app which set as default in React Native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way in React Native to find out, for example, which map app, browser, or whatever user has set by default on his device?

Comment: Are you trying to find out the name of the app specifically, or to send the user to the app, like you might with linking: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Comment: @TylerWilliams Thank you! For my current purpose linking works perfect, but yeah, I'm still interested how find out the name of the app specifically

Answer (score 0):

As we mentioned in the comments, opening apps from the phone can be handled by [Linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking)